# How do I make my post community-wiki using android app?

Tags: feature-request, android-app, community-wiki

I am using SE android app and want to make my post as community-wiki but can't see any option/feature for that.

Comment: There is not. Updated tags.

Answer (score 1):

This would be amazing!

When posts need to be CW, there should be an option to make them CW so it gets less messy. Anyways, the current way is to flag the post for moderator attention with a comment saying that the post needs to be marked CW. Great proposal that needs a big [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)!