# Development on the Android app seems ... kind of dead

Tags: discussion, feature-request, android-app

I do realise that it's a free application, and there's been [posts about it before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272122/why-has-stack-exchange-stopped-working-on-the-android-app).

It's 2017. We're having new bugs kicked up by the HTTPS upgrade. I personally have had issues with it opening posts in my browser, and well...

At the very least, another status update would be nice. I'm *primarily* relying on it for notifications (which breaks for some people) and we've gone through 2–3 major Android revisions so far.

If it's abandoned, it would be nice to know. Otherwise, essentially, it feels a lot like the application is going to gradually bleed users through neglect.

I've noticed the iOS app gets fixed so... can we see some love for our Android users?

Comment: I'm tempted to flag to close this as too broad.

Comment: Not sure I can narrow it - Yeah, there's a bunch of *individual* issues, but the big issue is that development has frozen for an extended period of time. Its probably not even that great a question, outside a certain degree of awareness raising.

Comment: As of 31.08.2017 it's semi-official that the android app is currently [not developed, and will not be for the forseeable / immediate future](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/222299)

Comment: yanno? That answers this, I'm going to vote to close my own question as a duplicate of that.