# Are more mobile app review or moderation features coming?

Tags: discussion, android-app, ios-app

This is a little bit of a double-question.

1. Is the mobile app for Stack Exchange (in particular for iOS) still being developed?
2. Is there any hope for adding in advanced features for the various review/mod tools?

(*NOTE: To distinguish my question, I am specifically referring to the review and mod tools, not just the users' edit/delete functions.*)

I understand that this would be a bit of work in both the front and back-end development if it's not already been put into play, so I don't have any expectations.

Comment: I think its state is best described as *being looked after* which means a bug fix now and then but don't expect major new things. In regard to review and mod tools: those would need end-points in the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) first so if anything is going to happen with the mobile apps, it certainly won't be for those features in the next 6 to 8 weeks ...

Comment: The apps are dead. No updates in two years now. Sad really because I'm primarily on mobile and am active on multiple sites

Comment: Using it happily on iOS until last week. The last update to iOS 14.6 finally pulled the plug. So sad.

Comment: Related: *[Mobile app infrastructure has been decommissioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383026/)* (2022-10-19).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to a January 13, 2020 [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028/336163) by Yaakov Ellis ♦,

> We are not providing any further support for the mobile apps. There will not be any more builds made for either the Android or the iOS app (even for breaking bugs). We encourage all mobile users to use the responsive website. We hope to continue to incrementally improve the user experience for mobile users.

The answer thus appears to be "no".

Comment: I suppose if the website is responsive enough for mobile, then ultimately that would resolve the desire for those functions in an app. Don't need the app if the site is sufficient.

Comment: Instead of making the identical post, I will endorse this answer. Please consider this to be the canonical response to any questions asking for changes in the mobile apps.

Answer (score 41):

To put it bluntly, no and no.

New feature work on the apps has pretty much been frozen for the time being. Even if/when feature work resumes, I don't know if we'll ever reach a point where we're implementing moderator features, unless the narrative around the apps change dramatically.

I've been trying to write this a few different ways, and it keeps getting bleak really fast.

I'll just say that there's a much, much bigger bang for the buck right now having a Java and an Objective-C developer writing C# than there is doing feature work on the app. I'm forever the optimist and would love to see us return to full app work some day, but I don't know when that day will be.

The team isn't falling apart, the apps aren't going anywhere, but Brian and I are both slated to be full time on the DAG team for the foreseeable future.

A positive result of this (for me), is that Brian and I are both becoming more familiar with the web codebase, so for things that aren't implemented in the API yet (e.g. moderator features) we might be able to add them ourselves in the future.

Comment: That's an answer I've been waiting loooooooooooong time to hear. Thanks. No more speculations on my side from hearing things here and there. Bleak or bright, we deserve to know the truth. :)

Comment: Thanks for the update.  What is a DAG in this context?

Comment: @DGGenuine: [Meet Team DAG!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351751/meet-team-dag-developer-affinity-growth/)

Comment: "*the apps aren't going anywhere*" apparently [the SO one has gone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373307/2821954)?

Comment: I think your optimism was in vain. No app update in two years and the site is kinda clunky to manage multiple sites on mobile, plus no push notifications

Comment: I'd much rather a better app tbh

Comment: "the narrative around the apps" – What does that even mean?

Comment: When observing technology companies make strategic decisions, and I see them do something that the mainstream do not, I generally say to myself, 'No, its the rest of the world that are wrong.' I really cannot believe that there is no app anymore.