# Absence of Area 51 in site list in Android App

Tags: discussion, feature-request, android-app

I cannot find Area 51 in the site list in the Android app. Will this be implemented in the future?

Comment: Will this be implemented in future? No, it won't. Never.

Comment: Why? Can you explain?

Comment: Sure. As you can clearly see from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/152859), the android app development is frozen, for good. They won't add new features. And even if they did, something like this is in the very bottom of the list so would have taken long years until they even start to plan it.