# Distinguish between normal posts and community wiki posts in Android App

Tags: feature-request, bug, android-app, mobile-web, community-wiki

In the Android App, one cannot distinguish between normal posts abs community wiki ones. Firstly example, below is a screen shot of a question from the mobile view, and the same from the app:

[image]

Screenshot from app:

[image]

Why is there an anomaly like this? This should be edited as fast as possible.

Comment: @Cai that does provide an answer, but I want to know whether it will be implemented at any time, if at all.

Comment: [It won't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/307988) (at least not any time soon). There's basically no development on the Android app anymore.

Comment: @Cai is correct, too bad people waste their time asking for new features...

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I don't find anything wrong in requesting. It's up to the developers whether or not they'll listen.

Comment: It is misleading. For over a year we were in the dark, asking questions while there is nobody who even listens. This is really infuriating, at least for me.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd you're correct, but still, the new ones like me can at least keep trying. Maybe someday they'll listen............