# Can't paste on iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app, paste

I'm trying to copy and paste on the iOS app and I can't seem to. Whenever I click paste, nothing shows up, even though I have copied text to my clipboard. I've copied from the app and then pasted in different apps and it works, but I can't paste in the iOS app. My paste functionality works everywhere else.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 11.1.1 (Build 15B150)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Darn! That's really annoying.

Comment: True, what's more annoying is that Stack Exchange does not have iOS developer anymore (more accurate, the single iOS developer they have has been re-assigned to work on "ordinary" web projects), so this bug is never going to be fixed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard So the iOS app is becoming dormant like the Android one? I assume the SO app is also being 'abandoned'? Was there an announcement somewhere?

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/152859) includes both apps. Kasra was the mobile app team leader. Team DAG does not touch the apps. Moreover, I think Brian did try to fix stuff in his own free time, but was then forbidden by SE management from pushing the fix to production. Think it was mentioned in chat, will try to find it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's weird how they'd forbid a bug fix. Thanks for the link & insight.

Comment: [Found it](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=6242800#6242800). While not directly saying it, it's obvious that by "I'm just not pushing the release along like I otherwise would be" he means his hands are tied. Proof is that he still did not push anything to this day, three months after writing this. :-(