# iPhone app’s 3D Touch action button(s) should be more useful when peeking at a question

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

Currently the view shown when peeking at a question with the iOS app just has a Flag action:

[image]

but I think Favorite and/or Add to Reading List (Safari) would be particularly useful as action buttons when peeking at a question. Perhaps Upvote and Downvote as well.

3D Touch support in the overall Feed would be nice too, as you can only peek at questions when you’re in a particular SE site or in Inbox/Achievements/search.

Comment: Nice meta-y choice of screen shot. Be aware: [Are more mobile app review or moderation features coming?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/159251)