# Unabandon the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, android-app

The Android app *Stack Exchange* is really useful, but it needs some changes, for instance the ability to delete posts.

It really needs to be unabandoned!

Answer (score 8):

Sorry, we have no plans to revivify the Android App. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348076/51) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/51) for more info.