# Stack Exchange iOS app does not have Forgot Password

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

The Stack Exchange iOS app does not have the option for “Forgot Password” when trying to login. The Stack Overflow app does. It would be convenient if it was implemented.

Comment: The mobile apps are no longer maintained, sorry. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299862/are-more-mobile-app-review-or-moderation-features-coming