# Why can't own answers be deleted in the Android app?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, android-app, deleted-answers

I seem to recall asking for this feature some years ago and being told it wasn't going to happen, but it seems silly to me that if I suddenly realize I posted a stupid answer that can't be redeemed, I have to rush to open my web browser to delete it. So what is the reason for not allowing it?

Comment: Back when the app was in active development, no one bothered to implement it. Now the app is no longer being actively developed.

Comment: @Sonic That certainly explains it. Maybe you should post an answer.

Comment: Glorfindel already did.

Comment: A note, even if the app is no longer developped, the mobile site is nice.

Comment: @yagmoth There are issues with using a web browser on a small touch screen device. A clumsy touch can navigate you away, for one.

Comment: @Robert Even if the question is duplicate, the situation has changed and the answer is not.

Comment: @MattSamuel if you think that question deserves a better/updated answer you can always write one.

Comment: @Robert I asked this because I don't know the answer, and there's no way I can get a person to write a new answer for an old question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no good reason for it other than limited development time and resources back when the apps were being actively developed. It *is* possible from the iOS app, so the [API supports it](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/delete-answer). However, right now, [all development on the apps has been frozen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/295232).

And there's no real reason to *rush*; you can always delete an answer. A single downvoted deleted answer won't cause much harm (unless you're posting a lot of bad answers and are at the risk of a low-quality answer ban).

Comment: That's a shame. I've basically ceased to use my computer at home for anything but work because I can do almost everything I need on my phone, and the app is much easier to use than the site.

Comment: There is a bit of a reason to rush. Having -2 score and being deleted is worse for a ban than having -1 score and being deleted.

Comment: Sure, but that's only a problem if you're close to a ban anyway. Most users (especially those with 500 rep on Meta) don't come anywhere close.

Comment: The rushing part is more a matter of embarrassment than a ban. I don't like to post stupid things!

Comment: Trust me, most of us do that, and other people forget about it after 6-8 weeks. I still remember some of my own stupid answers, definitely.

Comment: @MattSamuel Also note that users can't see deleted posts on one's profile, even if they have 10k rep or more; only moderators can see deleted posts on one's profile.

Comment: @Sonic I haven't really spent much time on the site in a long time, really just using the app, but I recall being able to see recently deleted answers.

Comment: @MattSamuel You only see those on your own profile, not others'.