# Badges not hidden for suspended accounts on iOS app

Tags: bug, badges, ios-app, account-suspension

For suspended users, like the one who [answered my question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/5424/45), the number of badges they earned aren't shown in their user information box.

> [image]

Yet when I view this post in the Stack Exchange iOS app, the number of badges is not hidden:

> [image]

Can this be brought in line with how it works on the main site?

<sub>I'm aware [development on the apps is frozen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/295232); it's not a high priority issue but it could be put on the backlog when it resumes or the apps are open-sourced.</sub>

Comment: Huh when did we start hiding badges for suspended users? We didn't used to do that, and I'm not sure it makes any sense.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess it makes sense since it might confuse users – 'how can user X have a bunch of badges but only 1 reputation?'

Comment: That's just as easily done seeing a 1-reputation users with a highly upvoted post. Reputation was set to 1 to resemble their privileges being taken away for the suspension, but badges... are basically meaningless and I can't think of a better reason to hide them just because of a suspension.

Comment: @animuson It’s actually in the suspension faq: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125268/364003 second paragraph „During suspension“

Comment: @MEE Just added in October, so not a long change. Wish I could find the relevant discussion for the change, though.

Comment: @animuson not sure though whether the change in the code was earlier and nobody noticed until last year...