# Sign In with Apple will be required in the Stack Exchange iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

This is just a heads up to the people working on the iOS Stack Exchange app that a Sign In With Apple button will be required to be next to the Facebook and Google login buttons.

From [Updates to the App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=06032019j):

> Sign In with Apple will be available for beta testing this summer. It will be required as an option for users in apps that support third-party sign-in when it is commercially available later this year.

Comment: Not my downvote, but ... [there are no people working on the iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/295232).