# Can I use the Stack Exchange app to connect to our company's private Stack Overflow site?

Tags: support, android-app, ios-app, so-enterprise

We have our own instance of Stack Overflow web app which we access using https://stackoverflow.ourcompany.com.

Can I configure the mobile app to connect to that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I report bugs with or request features for the Stack Exchange mobile apps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348075/how-can-i-report-bugs-with-or-request-features-for-the-stack-exchange-mobile-app)

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not possible. You cannot configure anything in the app, all URLs are hardcoded to the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) and a few `mobile.stackexchange.com` endpoints. The apps don't even work with [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams), even though the API has [some support](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/teams) for it.

Since [development on the apps is frozen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/295232), you're better off building something yourself. I'm not sure if Stack Overflow for Enterprise already supports the new responsive design, which works pretty well on mobile. All you'd need is a small wrapper/container for push notifications, and you have a decent app. According to the [product splash page](https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise), it comes with an API you could use for this.

Comment: Does Stack Overflow for Teams comes with it's own dedicated private APIs?

Comment: [Yes, it does.](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/teams)