# I want to make the fonts bigger in the Stack Exchange iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

I think the fonts in the Stack Exchange iOS app are too small, and I want to regulate the length of them. Could you add this function?

Comment: Unfortunately the iOS app is no longer being developed or supported. All the updates and development time are going into the site experience, including making it responsive so it fits nicely in a mobile browser. Though I still strongly prefer the iOS app and its notification features, and use it daily and exclusively.

Comment: See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/273503

Comment: ，thanks you very much,

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using iOS Settings by navigating to General, then Accessibility and then to Larger Fonts.

Comment: Thanks, I know that way, but I just want fonts bigger in this app but all