# UI issue on Stack Overflow profile page: HTML is not decoding properly for the badge on the mobile app

Tags: bug, android-app, user-interface, mobile-app

As seen in the badge earned section, **amp;** instead of which **&** should be shown on the Stack Overflow  profile page.

- Android: [5.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Lollipop) (Lollipop).
- Stack Overflow app, latest version.

[image: Bug Image]

Comment: It's the StackOverflow app for android

Comment: Hp_issei, thanks for your report. Please note that work on the mobile app is [frozen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299862/282094) and fixes won't be forthcoming. I use an Android phone with Firefox (in desktop mode) with good results. Google Chrome and Opera work too.

Comment: Thanks, @Rob I didn't know that development is frozen for a mobile app I thought I shall report it.