# Rules and the App

Tags: feature-request, android-app, rules

I have noticed that there is no quick and easy way to read the rules for a given site if you are primarily using the Android App. This has resulted in my occasionally posting questions to the Law Stack Exchange forum in particular that aren't quite up to snuff.

Are there plans to make it easier for app users to know what the posting guidelines are?

Comment: FYI, the mobile apps [have not been maintained for the past several years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/258777); new features are almost certainly not going to be added for the time being.

Comment: Oh wow thank you. I feel pretty dumb now. I'll rely on the app less in the future.

Comment: Honestly, it's still a problem on the desktop sites as well that the rules aren't read enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whilst this is a good request a and could possibly reduce the number of off topic questions, app development [has stopped for a long while](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/258777). As mentioned, the app is almost never going to have the same features as the full website.

Work has been done for responsive design so the sites can be accessed on mobile. (I’m posting on the mobile site right now and it’s not that bad actually).

Comment: The mobile site is quite awful. Leaving comments is hard, flagging comments is impossible and chat doesn't work very well.

Comment: @Mast click enable full site at the bottom of the page on mobile