# Meta sites are missing reputation in the Your Communities list in the Stack Exchange iOS app

Tags: bug, reputation, ios-app, api

Reputation for per-site metas is not shown in the 'Your Communities' list in the sidebar menu of the Stack Exchange iOS app (anymore – it used to work before).

[image]

App development is currently [frozen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/295232), but this looks like a bug solely caused by the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/). I suspect the app uses the `/me/associated` API method, and it doesn't seem to return data about meta sites anymore. You can test this with [this call](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-associated-users#types=meta_site&filter=default&run=true) (remember to click the 'Get Token' button); compare that to the result when you leave the `types` parameter empty.

[image]

Comment: Considering MSO rep should be the same (although lagging behind a bit at times) as SO rep (which is listed above MSO), it could be seen as a feature. Less clutter.