# Search for existing questions asked by someone else

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Please add the search feature for the existing questions asked by someone else, which the current user is going to ask. How to see the answers to my questions if the same is asked and answered previously by someone else?

Comment: Well it should be in the profile page in the app. It's working for years in the iOS app. Android app is dead for long time and will shut down soon anyway.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I haven't seen any official updates on [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272419/295232) (but it's 6-8 seasons old) – is that pure speculation about shutting down or do you have more information? *sent from my iPhone*

Comment: @Glorfindel shut down [was informally announced in MSO as comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349255/stack-overflow-now-has-its-own-app-on-ios-and-android#comment473543_349255) (*but in 6 months my team might be doing mobile-web if that helps the company more* - the meaning is clear, right? So we have three more months to enjoy the app)

Comment: @ShadowWizard yeah, that counts. Thanks for digging it up.