# Not receiving notifications on mobile

Tags: bug, android-app

I only see that someone has responded to me through the feed on my phone, never through the notifications on the top right. Then, a couple days later, they will pop up for the ones that have been updated in my feed, but not anything newer. If I didn't see it in my feed, it won't later pop up in notifications, even if I notice it through looking at the question again. This has been happening for only about two months now.

Using the Stack Exchange app on a Galaxy S8+

Android is version 8.0.0

Comment: I see some OLD duplicates, but thought the question could be refreshed since it's still happening (to me at least).

Comment: Is this the app or mobile web?

Comment: @Laurel the app

Comment: I *really* don't think the app is supported anymore.

Comment: Hasn't been for ages

Comment: @RoryAlsop and makoto. ah, thanks. It'd been working perfectly until a couple months ago. Ah well, minor issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are more mobile app review or moderation features coming?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299862/are-more-mobile-app-review-or-moderation-features-coming) and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272122/why-has-stack-exchange-stopped-working-on-the-android-app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why has Stack Exchange stopped working on the Android app?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272122/why-has-stack-exchange-stopped-working-on-the-android-app)

Comment: It is a very broad definition of "duplicate". All Android app bug reports and feature requests will be duplicates of the canonical question stating that the Android app is no longer being developed. (Also note that "Possible duplicate of" comments like Nathan's are auto-generated by the system when people cast votes to mark this question as an actual duplicate, so Nathan wasn't just repeating himself. The system was repeating himself for him.)

Comment: @CodyGray ok. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: Related: [iPhone push notifications - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394972/iphone-push-notifications)