# Android app notifications without Google Play services (GCM)

Tags: feature-request, android-app, notifications

I'm using the Stack Exchange Android app, but it did not get any notification. The problem here is that I run Lineage OS and don't have any Google apps installed (including Play Store and the Play Services).

Since the Stack Exchange app uses Google Cloud Messaging for push notifications, is there an alternative to get notifications in the Android app or will this be possible in the future?

By the way, I have enabled notifications in the settings.

Comment: Related: [Not receiving notifications on mobile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325768/295232)

Comment: Did you try logging out of the app, killing it, and logging back in? I got a new phone and that worked for me.

Comment: @SonictheBracketedHedgehog Yes, but it does not work for me, because the Play Services are missing on my phone. Anything else works perfectly.

Comment: Wait...there's an *app*?

Comment: @RobertColumbia https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin